# Structuring a model - MVC (PHP)

Tags: model-view-controller, validation, codeigniter, model

How should one structure validation, preparation and arrangement (etc) of data before dealing with the DB?

The data I expect to be passed might need to be validated (ex: category `books` actually exists) or contain conditional values (ex: sale price should only be set if `ad` = `sale`) or values that must be converted to ids (ex: category `books` must be converted to category_id `123`).

I imagine that there are numerous ways to go about this like clumping everything together, grouping by field (do validation, prep etc together per field) or separating by action (validation, prep, etc) and field.

Are there any concepts when it comes to this topic just like the concept of MVC exists? Achieving flexibility, ease of maintenance or something like that?

Anything relating to common used components of model?

(I'm not sure if it helps but I'm currently using CodeIgniter / PHP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In codeigniter, you can use the Form_Validation class with a callback method that you create. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks.

In your callback method you can check to see if things exist in database, etc.

Comment: POST data would be accessed directly in the Model, no? I think I'd also have problems doing manipulations using Form_validation since, in case of Model failure, post values would not be the original values when repopulating the form. (ex: if you trim a value and the model->insert() didn't work out, you'd have something like 'string' instead of ' string'

Comment: Post data comes in to the controller. You can pass it to the model if you like to. What does model failure have to do with repopulating the form fields? In the case of checking if a category exists in the db, just do the check and if it doesn't exist, return false and repopulate the form field with what was submitted. You don't have to necessarily modify it. Just start digging with the way i've suggested and post again when you get stuck. What you're trying to accomplish is very easy in codeigniter.